# How to check wheather a variable is not a number ? Java

Tags: java, parseint

How am I supposed to check if my variable is different than a number (for example it's a char or a String). What Am I supposed to put in the if statement? x and y are read from the console

```
x = Integer.parseInt(Terminal.readLine());
y = Integer.parseInt(Terminal.readLine());

if () {
    bombInput = false;
    Terminal.printLine("Wrong input. Try again");
} else {
    bombInput = true;
}
```

Comment: Well you've already tried to convert the input to numbers - if you've got as far as your `if` statement without an exception, you managed to parse them...

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` will throw a [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) if the input is not a valid machine-formatted `int`.  If you want to take input from a real person though, you should look into [`java.text.DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) since real people tend to use commas or dots to separate digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
    x = Integer.parseInt(Terminal.readLine());
    //it's an int
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    //not an integer
}
```

But you could also create a utility function, if the overhead is not too much:

```
public static boolean isInteger(final String s) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
        return true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
String xAsString = Terminal.readLine();
if(isInteger(xAsString)){
    x = Integer.parseInt(xAsString);
} else {
    // :(
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if instead of the if-else, you do this:

```
try {
    x = Integer.parseInt(Terminal.readLine());
    y = Integer.parseInt(Terminal.readLine());
    bombInput = true;
}
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    bombInput = false;
    Terminal.printLine("Wrong input. Try again");
}
```

The `Integer.parseInt` calls will throw a `NumberFormatException` if they're given bad input.

Answer (score 0):

```
String x = Terminal.readLine();
if (x != null) {
    //use regex
    if (x.matches("\\d")) {
        //input is a number
        //parse the input
    } else {
        //input is not a number

    }
}
```

Comment: Umm... that will work only if the input string is one digit long.  Try adding `+` after `\\d`.  Also we need to know whether negative numbers and numbers beginning with a plus sign (`'+'`) are acceptable.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on your answer?